# Does "ser loco" vs. "estar loco" work the same as in Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas, diferencias-entre-palabras

In Brazilian Portuguese, both "estar louco" and "ser louco" may be used literally to refer to an insane person in a madhouse or figuratively to someone with a wild, unpredictable behavior. The only difference is that the former expression focuses on the current state and the latter implies that it is a permanent state.

Are "estar loco" and "ser loco" used identically in Spanish? Could I use both when talking to a friend? Example:

- ¡Estás loco si quieres tomar cerveza ahora!
- ¡Eres (un) loco!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spanish, "loco" works just as described in Brazilian Portuguese.

With an article in the singular, "ser un loco/una loca" will tend to describe a temporary behavior, not a mental condition.

- Está loco. Tienen que llevarlo a un psiquiatra. (mental condition, usually temporary or new)
- Es loco. No puedes hablar con él como si fuera una persona cuerda. (permanent mental condition)
- ¡Está loco! ¡Cómo va a hacer eso! (behavior)
- ¡Es un loco! ¡Cómo va a hacer eso! (behavior)

Comment: "Es loco" is unusual in Spain, we'd say either "es un loco" or "está loco" and in both cases it may refer to someone that is literally insane or just acts as one

Comment: @Patricio Here it can work as an adjective with "ser" just like "es psicótico".

Comment: I'd say that "es una locura" is more frequent in Spain